# Intellisense and code formatting T-SQL for SQL Server 2008 in Visual Studio 2008?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, visual-studio-2008, code-formatting

I'm looking for a Visual Studio 2008 add-in / plug-in that can provide Intellisense and flexible code formatting for T-SQL for use with SQL Server 2008.  It needs to work with Team System Data Edition ("data dude").

I am familiar with the Red Gate tools, but they do much more than I need—which unfortunately puts the price on the high side.  A web search turned up a couple of others, but it's hard to tell how polished or complete they are without trying each one...

Also, I heard a rumor that Intellisense for T-SQL might be included with VS 2010.  It wasn't there in Beta 1, AFAICT.  Does anyone know more?

Comment: SQL Prompt by Red Gate is the only tool I know that does this, sorry. The "non-PRO" version is $195 which isn't too much considering the time and effort it can save you day by day by day.....

Comment: Unfortunately, I think you need the Pro version to get T-SQL formatting, which adds another $100. If it was core to my work, I could probably justify it, but it's not.

Comment: I decided to give the SQL Prompt free trial a go. I expected it to have a richer feature set on the formatting side, and to not be so buggy (it does a spectacularly poor job with the MERGE statement).  Even if it was free, I don't think I'd use the formatter.  Oh well.  Maybe Intellisense will be better....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also download the trial of [SQL Assistant](http://www.softtreetech.com/isql.htm) to see if it fits your needs.  It works in VS2008.  I purchased and used it before I got the Red Gate tools and actually liked it.  It's only $149.

Comment: I downloaded the trial, and I'm working my way through it. Better than SQL Prompt so far, on the formatting side at least. However, it's still surprisingly buggy for a commercial tool: poor support for MERGE and Service Broker commands, for example.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use the SQL client tools, "Intellisense" is included in Management Studio for SQL Server 2008 already.

edit: For formatting, you can also use [SSMS Tools Pack](http://www.ssmstoolspack.com/) but again it's SSMS only...

Comment: Trying to manage copy-and-paste back-and-forth between SSMS and VS is way too error prone for me. I do my coding in VS, deploy from there to SQL using auto-generated scripts, and use SSMS only for debugging or maintenance.

Comment: I tend to work only in SSMS because I'm a developer DBA (although many of my colleagues do too, but we use Red Gate pro)